# What does 'required' validator in Mongoose actually do?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

[Mongoose docs about `required` validator](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-required) don't include any explanation what `required` actually means.

I assume it's pretty obvious that `undefined` won't pass this validator and all values that evaluate to true (`!!v`) will be allowed. But what about null and empty string?

If they don't pass that validator, is there a standard Mongoose way to allow anything other than `undefined` or is writing a custom validator the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [`validation`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html)

> Validators are not run on `undefined` values. The only exception is the *required* validator.

Test this following schema

```
var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    body: {
        type: String, required: true
    }
});
```

Save the `body` field with `null` and `''`,

```
   var c1 = new Comment({
        body: null, 
    });

   var c1 = new Comment({
        body: '', 
    });
```

Both of them are failed to pass validation.

<s>To only validate `undefined`, I think it could be done through custom validate</s>

<s>CommentSchema.path('body').validate(function(body) {
        return typeof body !=== 'undefined';
    }, 'Body cannot be undefined');</s>

Update: Refer to this [link](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/941)

> running validators on undefined fields is not supported and currently not planned

Several tricks are done in this link.

Comment: You've said it yourself that validators don't run on undefined values. How is that custom validator supposed to work? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to zangw answer, currently the only reasonable way to allow anything other than `undefined` is to pass a custom function to `required` property. It can't be done via `validate` as custom validators aren't run on undefined values.

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    field: { type: String, required: function ()
    {
        return this.field === undefined;
    }}
});
```